# Golang compile for all platforms in Windows 7 (32 bit)

Tags: windows, go, cross-platform, cross-compiling

I'm using windows 7 [32 bit] operating system.

I'm build example go program.

I want to compile this program for all platforms from my windows 7 [32 bit] OS.

I want to compile my program for all `Linux [32/64] / Mac OSX [32/64] / Windows[32/64]`.

Is it possible are not from my single OS ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Update Go 1.5: see "[Cross compilation just got a whole lot better in Go 1.5](http://dave.cheney.net/2015/03/03/cross-compilation-just-got-a-whole-lot-better-in-go-1-5)"

> For successful cross compilation you would need
>
> - compilers for the target platform, if they differed from your host platform, ie you’re on darwin/amd64 (6g) and you want to compile for linux/arm (5g).
> - a standard library for the target platform, which included some files generated at the point your Go distribution was built.
>
> With the plan to translate the [Go compiler into Go](http://golang.org/s/go13compiler) coming to fruition in the 1.5 release the first issue is now resolved.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "runtime"

func main() {
        fmt.Printf("Hello %s/%s\n", runtime.GOOS, runtime.GOARCH)
}
```

> build for darwin/386

```
% env GOOS=darwin GOARCH=386 go build hello.go
# scp to darwin host
$ ./hello
Hello darwin/386
```

> Or build for linux/arm

```
% env GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=7 go build hello.go
# scp to linux host
$ ./hello
Hello linux/arm
```

---

Original answer (Go 1.4 and before)

You can try a tool like [`gox`](https://github.com/mitchellh/gox)

> Gox is a simple, no-frills tool for Go cross compilation that behaves a lot like standard go build.
>   Gox will parallelize builds for multiple platforms.
>   Gox will also build the cross-compilation toolchain for you.
>
> Before you use Gox, you must build the cross-compilation toolchain. Gox can do this for you. This only has to be done once (or whenever you update Go):

```
$ gox -build-toolchain
```

You will also find many cross-platform development tips at "[Developing for Multiple Platforms With Go](http://techblog.steelseries.com/2014/04/08/multi-platform-development-go.html)".

[Passionate Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/841090/passionate-developer) points out [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051623/golang-compile-for-all-platforms-in-windows-7-32-bit/25052191#comment41012938_25052191) to [issue 19](https://github.com/mitchellh/gox/issues/19), left by the [OP Nakka Chandra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1797772/nakka-chandra), even though [issue 10](https://github.com/mitchellh/gox/issues/10#issuecomment-42777264) reported making gox run successfully on Windows.

Comment: This doesn't work on windows refer to this link for details `https://github.com/mitchellh/gox/issues/19`

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper true, that issue was left by the OP. Yet, issue 10 reports good success with gox on Windows. I have included both in the answer.

Comment: Yeap but I wasn't able to run it on windows and there are no instructions for this anywhere. Have you successfully ran on Windows at all?

Answer (score 4):

On Windows run the following commands:

```
C:\Users\user\go\src\myapp> set GOOS=linux  
C:\Users\user\go\src\myapp> set GOARCH=amd64  
C:\Users\user\go\src\myapp> go build
```

It worked for me.

Notice, if you get the error:

> cmd/go: unsupported GOOS/GOARCH pair linux/amd64

This is because you have a space at the end of the variable.
Example, wrong use is:  `set GOOS=linux<space>)`, instead it should be:  `set GOOS=linux`.

This is the full table list (taken from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-go-executables-for-multiple-platforms-on-ubuntu-16-04)) for all the other systems:

```
    GOOS - Target Operating System| GOARCH - Target Platform
   -------------------------------|--------------------------
   |           android            |           arm           |  
   |           darwin             |           386           |  
   |           darwin             |           amd64         |    
   |           darwin             |           arm           |  
   |           darwin             |           arm64         |    
   |           dragonfly          |           amd64         |    
   |           freebsd            |           386           |  
   |           freebsd            |           amd64         |    
   |           freebsd            |           arm           |  
   |           linux              |           386           |  
   |           linux              |           amd64         |    
   |           linux              |           arm           |  
   |           linux              |           arm64         |    
   |           linux              |           ppc64         |    
   |           linux              |           ppc64le       |      
   |           linux              |           mips          |   
   |           linux              |           mipsle        |     
   |           linux              |           mips64        |     
   |           linux              |           mips64le      |       
   |           netbsd             |           386           |  
   |           netbsd             |           amd64         |    
   |           netbsd             |           arm           |  
   |           openbsd            |           386           |  
   |           openbsd            |           amd64         |    
   |           openbsd            |           arm           |  
   |           plan9              |           386           |  
   |           plan9              |           amd64         |    
   |           solaris            |           amd64         |    
   |           windows            |           386           |   
   |           windows            |           amd64         |
   ----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Where can I find an updated list for this? It seems strange, but I can't find an official list of all possible cross-compilation targets anywhere.

Comment: Just run `go tool dist list`

Answer (score 1):

You can find the full list of supported GOOS/GOARCH platforms supported by your `go` by running `go tool dist list`.

For Go 1.18.1, this shows the following pairs, after filtering based on the target OSes you said you are interested in:

```
$ go tool dist list | grep -e linux -e darwin -e windows
darwin/amd64
darwin/arm64
linux/386
linux/amd64
linux/arm
linux/arm64
linux/mips
linux/mips64
linux/mips64le
linux/mipsle
linux/ppc64
linux/ppc64le
linux/riscv64
linux/s390x
windows/386
windows/amd64
windows/arm
windows/arm64
```

If you want to compile your code for all of these, you can do this with the bash/sh script below:

```
bin_name='example'  # Change the binary name as desired

go tool dist list | grep -e linux -e darwin -e windows | while read -r pair; do
    # Extract the GOOS and GOARCH from the pair
    GOOS="${pair%/*}"
    GOARCH="${pair#*/}"

    suffix=''
    # If GOOS is windows, set suffix to .exe
    [ "$GOOS" = 'windows' ] && suffix='.exe'

    # Replace <args> with appropriate arguments as needed
    GOOS="$GOOS" GOARCH="$GOARCH" \
        go build -o "${bin_name}-${GOOS}-${GOARCH}${suffix}" <args>
done
```

This script will produce an executable for each OS/architecture pair, and append the OS and architecture at the end of the name. It will also append `.exe` if the OS is Windows.